# How to insert multiple rows at the same time into a Mysql table in Android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite, web-services

I have to retrieve all the rows from a sqlite table and insert them in mysql via PHP webservice but only the first row was inserted.
How to insert multiple rows at the same time into a Mysql table in Android?

*code to retrieve sqlite data*

```
  public String getName(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT NOMBRE FROM BEBIDAS",null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        return cursor.getString(0);
    }
    return "";
}
public int getPrecio(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT PRECIO FROM BEBIDAS",null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
public int getCantidad(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT CANTIDAD FROM BEBIDAS",null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*Volley Request to pass details to webservice*

```
private void insertData(String URL){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.isEmpty()){
                Intent confirm = new Intent(Pagos_Lugares.this, elegirPrefer.class);
                startActivity(confirm);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(Pagos_Lugares.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            CafeteriaDB cafe= new CafeteriaDB(getApplicationContext());
            Map<String,String> parametros = new HashMap<String,String>();
            parametros.put("nombre",cafe.getName());
            parametros.put("precio",String.valueOf(cafe.getPrecio()));
            parametros.put("cantidad",String.valueOf(cafe.getCantidad()));
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

*web service - php code is given below*

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$precio=$_POST['precio'];
$cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];

$consulta="INSERT INTO ordenes_bebidas VALUES('".$nombre."','".$precio."','".$cantidad."')";

mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

*Thanks*

Comment: cursor value has been replaced with the next one ?

Comment: in sqlite, yes but in the mysql table only the first row is inserted (as if the sqlite table had only one row), but if it has more rows it does not insert them.

Comment: Let's see where you're calling `insertData`.

Comment: in mysql, in the web service